# Graylog2: Can a custom GELF field accept a JSON object

Tags: graylog

I was just reading the [GELF](https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-docs/wiki/GELF) spec as I'm integrating it into our system. I was just wondering if an additional/custom field can contain a JSON object as the spec doesn't mention it:

So my GELF output (in particular the _request field below) would look something like:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "host": "www1",
  "short_message": "Short message",
  "full_message": "Backtrace here\n\nmore stuff",
  "timestamp": 1291899928,
  "level": 1,
  "facility": "payment-backend",
  "file": "/var/www/somefile.rb",
  "line": 356,
  "_request": {
      "ip": "123.123.123.123",
      "url": "example.com/dir/file.ext",
      "method": "get",
      "referer" "example.net"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently GELF doesn't support nested JSON objects however if anyone is interested please comment at [groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/graylog2/Xg3v3Qh8fmo](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/graylog2/Xg3v3Qh8fmo).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to avoid such nested structures, it will just complicate things. You can flatten it out and put this into the JSON instead:

```
_request_ip
_request_url
_request_method
_request_referer
```

Comment: I had considered this however for complex stack traces it would make sense to include it as a JSON object and would make it much simpler to read. So I was wondering if the GELF standard allows for this? I'm not a Graylog2 user so I'm not sure if it even supports it but I did want to make my application compatible.

Comment: Hey Sean, please post this as a suggestion on the Graylog2 mailing list, so we can discuss this!

Comment: @Lennart Cheers, posted it at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/graylog2/Xg3v3Qh8fmo